# Unmet dependencies and cannot fix or install them

Tags: upgrade

```
benjamin@benjamin-ThinkPad-X260:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall  libgl1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 : Depends: libgl-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libglvnd-dev : Depends: libegl-dev (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgl-dev (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgles-dev (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libglx-dev (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
 libglvnd-dev:i386 : Depends: libegl-dev:i386 (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgl-dev:i386 (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgles-dev:i386 (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libglx-dev:i386 (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
 python : PreDepends: python-minimal (= 2.7.15~rc1-1) but 2.7.15-3~oibaf~b is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
benjamin@benjamin-ThinkPad-X260:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
benjamin@benjamin-ThinkPad-X260:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdrm-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-core-dev:i386 libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev
  libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxdamage-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxshmfence-dev libxxf86vm-dev mesa-common-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libegl-dev libegl-dev:i386 libgl-dev libgl-dev:i386 libgles-dev libgles-dev:i386 libglx-dev libglx-dev:i386 libpython-stdlib
  libpython2-stdlib python python2
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk python2-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libegl-dev libegl-dev:i386 libgl-dev libgl-dev:i386 libgles-dev libgles-dev:i386 libglx-dev libglx-dev:i386 libpython2-stdlib python2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython-stdlib python
2 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
66 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/478 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4.240 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 255672 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libglx-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/0-libglx-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/glx.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:i386 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../1-libgl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/1-libgl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/gl.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:i386 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../2-libglx-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-dev:i386 (1.3.1-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/2-libglx-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/glx.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:i386 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../3-libgl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl-dev:i386 (1.3.1-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/3-libgl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/gl.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:i386 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../4-libegl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libegl-dev:i386 (1.3.1-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/4-libegl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/EGL/egl.h', which is also in package libegl1-mesa-dev:i386 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to unpack .../5-libgles-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles-dev:i386 (1.3.1-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/5-libgles-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h', which is also in package libgles2-mesa-dev:i386 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to unpack .../6-libegl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/6-libegl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/EGL/egl.h', which is also in package libegl1-mesa-dev:i386 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to unpack .../7-libgles-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/7-libgles-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h', which is also in package libgles2-mesa-dev:i386 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/0-libglx-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/1-libgl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/2-libglx-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/3-libgl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/4-libegl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/5-libgles-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/6-libegl-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-QGZVH6/7-libgles-dev_1.3.1-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I cannot find the dependencies to install and when I try to it goes gives me the same error, and goes around in a circle...any ideas?

**update:**

```
benjamin@benjamin-ThinkPad-X260:~$ apt-cache policy mesa-common-dev
mesa-common-dev:
  Installed: 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Candidate: 20.2~git2007261930.18fe13~oibaf~b
  Version table:
     20.2~git2007261930.18fe13~oibaf~b 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     20.1.4~kisak1~b 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
benjamin@benjamin-ThinkPad-X260:~$ apt-cache policy libgl-dev
libgl-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.3.1-1~oibaf~b
  Version table:
     1.3.1-1~oibaf~b 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1.3.0-7~kisak~b 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm getting the same errors you had initially, but not using any PPA's. :/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's trying to install the same files both from oibaf's PPA and additionally from the default Ubuntu sources. I'd be tempted to try simply purging and then re-adding the PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

And hopefully that will clear the conflict without anything more onerous being necessary. If not, some investigation will be required.

Comment: hmmm, 'E: Unable to locate package ppa-purge' is the output.
'

Comment: maybe this? https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ppa-purge

Comment: E: Unable to locate package every time I try to install something

Comment: @Benjamin something is quite severely broken then. Try searching for "Software Sources" in the dash and running the program. On the first tab, tick the top 4 boxes and close. Then in terminal, run `sudo apt update`, and see if you can install anything now

Comment: good news, the four checkboxes were unchecked (have no clue how), so I now am able to install ppa-purge, but the second command gives me 'sudo: ppa-purge: command not found', I added the new log to my question! :)

Comment: @Benjamin d'oh, of course it won't install ppa-purge when apt's broken. Just try this confirm something for me; `apt-cache policy mesa-common-dev` and then `apt-cache policy libgl-dev` - this basically is "Show me where I can get these packages from"